# Python dictionary where values are optional

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am looking for something in between a set and a dictionary. A set of unique keys, where some of the keys have values, but not all.

I could use a dictionary with value None meaning no value, but that gets verbose when most keys have no value: `{1: 'one', 2: None, 3: None}`. I want it to be just `{1: 'one', 2, 3}`, but that's a syntax error.

Is there something like this in Python? `defaultdict` doesn't help here. That makes default values when you read from the dict, not when adding keys.

If you want a motivation, I am trying to store a set C #defines that are passed to the compiler as `-DSOMETHING` without value or `-DSOMETHING=FOO` with.

Comment: It seems to me that you will have to go with `{1: 'one', 2: None, 3: None}`

Comment: Think of your #defines as *flags*: `{'SOMETHING': True, 'SOMETHINGELSE': 'FOO'}`…

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need the keys in the dictionary at all? You could implement the dictionary like this:

```
d = {1: 'one', 2: 'present'}
```

And then when you're working with the dictionary, you can do this:

```
one = d.get(1, None) # 'one'
two = d.get(2, None) # 'two'
three = d.get(3, None) # None
```

Maybe I could just add, you can have the full list of keys in a set:

```
keys = set([1,2,3])
```

And use that in the lookup:

```
for key in keys:
    value = d.get(key, None)
    if value is not None:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Here's another option. Use Tuples:

```
data = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'present'), (3,)]

for item in data:
    key = item[0]
    if len(item)>1:
         value = item[1]
    else:
         value = None
```

Comment: I mostly want a compact way of initializing the data structure in Python code. The tuple method at the end is quite nice.

Comment: I worried when you said that using Nones was verbose that you were hard-coding the whole thing by hand. Can you not generate it? If it is a configuration file, maybe store as json and load up.